# How to Use Recursion to Return a String?

Tags: c++, recursion

I am trying to solve this **recursively**. I am having a hard time returning the string:

```
string reverse(string);

int main() {
    cout << reverse("1234") << endl;

} // end main

string reverse(string integer) {
    if (integer == "")
        return "";
    else
        return reverse(integer.substr(1, integer.length()));
} // end reverse
```

I know the function has small issue (I hope). Can you please help me **fix it**? Thanks,

Comment: _"Can you please help me figure it out?"_ Well all of your [_'small issue'_](http://ideone.com/ZzhiuT) seems to be,  you `return "";` finally.

Comment: Edited the question just for you,

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ that part is fine, the other return statement needs fixing

Comment: How would you fix it?

Comment: Downvoted as *the question does not show any research effort*. You should try to solve the problem yourself first, and if you cannot solve it then explain what you have tried and what you don't understand.

Comment: I tried Matt. Believe me! I am new to recursion and trying to challenge myself by forcing to produce solutions using recursion so I can get better at it. Sorry if I don't impress you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
string reverse(string integer) {
    if (integer.length() == 0)
        return "";
    else
        return reverse(integer.substr(1, integer.length())) + integer.substr(0,1);
} // end reverse
```

See [live demo](http://ideone.com/ZzhiuT).

Comment: Well Done Mr. Flow! Thank you!

Comment: Btw, why did you vote down the question? Please advice me so I don't make the same mistake again.

Comment: @user3700785 _"Btw, why did you vote down the question?"_ Because I had to fix several issues (as e.g. `void main()`, etc.) , to get the code you posted compiled. (Retracted my DV now BTW)

Comment: The code compiled fine on mine accept the #include part I needed to add. But now I know. Next time I am including the complete required structure. Thank you again. It work beautifully! :)

Comment: @user3700785 Yes, e.g. Visual Studio is notoriously lax with such errors. I'd recommend using an online IDE like ideone (as was used for my experiments), or [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/), to make your reproducible codes in 1st place.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you keep recursing on shorter strings until you reach the empty string.
Since you never *do* anything with the result of the recursive call, you also end up with the empty string.

If you want the first character of the string to wind up in the result, you need to use it *somewhere*, you can't just throw it away.

You should put the first character at the back of the result of reversing the rest of the string, like this:

```
string reverse(string s)
{
    if (s == "")
        return "";
    else
        return reverse(s.substr(1, s.length())) + s[0];
}
```

or, shorter

```
string reverse(string s)
{
    return s.empty() ? "" : reverse(s.substr(1)) + s[0];
}
```